# How to upload universal nuxt application on my aws server?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to upload my universal nuxt app to my aws server. I have created node server but when i access my domain it give me proxy error on console.

> `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)`

All help appreciated.

[My Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6sgo.png)

Comment: probably u have some code?

Comment: Ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When i click any url, we get Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /podcasts/reply-all/episodes/96255/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1:3333podcasts